# Not incrementing as expected while using setInterval() in reactjs functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement an simple timer which sets its state after each second in setInterval()
But initially for few seconds it increments but later instead of increase in 1 second, it goes beyond  increment of 1.

```
import { useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
  var date = new Date();
  const [getdate,setDate]=useState("time");
   let handle=()=>{
    setDate(
    date.toTimeString()
      )
   }
   setInterval(handle,1000)
  
  
  return <div className="App">
  <b>{getdate}</b>
  <button onClick={handle}>Get</button>
  </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [getdate, setDate] = useState("time");

 const startTimer = () => {
  let handle = () => {
    let date = new Date();
    setDate(date.toTimeString());
  };
  setInterval(handle, 1000);
 }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <b>{getdate}</b>
      <button onClick={startTimer}>Get</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and for your second example. Make sure you don't call setInterval directly in the component..it should be inside a useEffect like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [count, setcount] = useState(30);
  useEffect(() => {
    let handle = () => {
      setcount((prev) => prev - 1);
    };
    setInterval(handle, 1000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {" "}
      <b>{count}</b>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what was wrong with my code?

Comment: Now this code fails work as expected
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setcount] = useState(30);


  let handle = ()=>{
    setcount(prev=>prev-1);
  };
  

 setInterval(handle, 1000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <b>{count}</b>
   
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: you are still doing the same thing as before...you should not put set Interval on its own like that..it should go in an useEffect

Comment: Thanks
So when ever i use setInterval() i need to put into some block of code and not independent
Can u tell me why is it so?

Comment: if you put it on its own it will run every time the component is rerendered...since you keep changing the state, the component will keep setting intervals...so you'll have a lot of intervals running. If you only do it in the useEffect when the component mounts...it won't to it on every rerender

Comment: You need to `clearInterval` that should be present in the return statement.

Comment: Oh okay now for my second example... how do i stop the timer when it reaches 0. How do i exit from the useEffect block

Comment: What should be the parameter in clearInterval